# IF operator not working in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Why does this batch code not work?
I certainly don't know why...
Download: http://tufda.net/downloads/explore/StackOverflow%20files/ultraworld.bat

```
@echo on
cls
set game=UltraWorld
echo Welcome to %game%!
PAUSE
cls
echo What's your name?:
set /p playername=""
cls
echo Welcome to %game%, %playername%!
PAUSE
:titlescreen
cls
echo Commands:
echo   new
echo   load
echo   credits
echo.
set /p command1=Enter your command here: 
IF command1==new (
set /p gamesave1=What name will you give this save?
)
IF command1==load (
echo No.
PAUSE
goto titlescreen
)
IF command1=="credits" (echo Everything - tufda & PAUSE & goto titlescreen)
PAUSE
```

Comment: You need to use percent symbols to reference your variables.  You must also remember that your IF commands are doing STRING comparisons.  That means the QUOTES are also apart of the string comparision: `IF "%command1%"=="credits" (echo Everything - tufda & PAUSE & goto titlescreen)`

Answer (score 0):

When you test the variable, you need to either surround it in percentage marks, or surround it with exclamation marks, if

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

is used.

For example,

```
IF %command1%==load (
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the IF command in a batch file, you need to follow the proper syntax.

The correct way to write an IF command is:

```
IF /I "%command1%" EQU "new" (
```

The Quotes arround each side will account for an empty value, while the EQU is the comarison type which is equivelant to ==. The comparisons are as follows:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

I used a /I to indicate that the comparison is not case sensitive.